# Wordpress title not displaying in browser title bar

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Website title is not displaying in browser title bar.

I have seen page source in browser and notice that ,  tags are repeating. This could be a probelm. I am unable to find the repetition.

This is the code of my header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 6]>
<html id="ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html id="ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html id="ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 6) | !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<title><?php

    global $page, $paged;

    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );

    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'name' );

    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";

    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'oscar' ), max( $paged, $page ) );

    ?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<?php

    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );

    wp_head();

?>

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Also I am calling <?php get_header(); ?> function in index.php and there is no <doctype> or <html> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, Wordpress was trying to print errors or warning message. But `'WP_DEBUG'` was false in `WP_CONFIG.PHP`.
I just make `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

It displayed some warning messages.

Comment: That still doesn't explain your double `html` tags

Answer (score 2):

**Look at your source code**, you have 2 `doctypes`, `html`, `head,` `body` and `title` tags.
You need to figure out where those are comming from.
probably there are html tags above the `<?php get_header(); ?>` part.

Is it your own theme?

**update**
To figure out where this is coming from deactivate all plugins.
If that helps turn them on one by one again to see which one does it.

If that doesn't help. turn off `fucntions.php` (rename it for now).
If that doesn't help give us a list of all (php) files in your theme.

Comment: Yes this is my own theme.
There is no html above <?php get_header();?>

Comment: @SMacFadyen I don't see that in the source code, and that isn't the problem

Comment: The problem is 

wp_enqueue_script was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the <code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>, <code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>, or <code>init</code> hooks. Please see <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2748

How to solve this?

Comment: if you remove this it works? if so fix your wp_enqueue, Good tutorial on this -> http://halfelf.org/2012/jquery-why-u-no-enqueued/

Answer (score 0):

The reason not to displaying the title in your page is exactly this - having 2 **head**, **title** tags, and closing the **head** tag twice. That means, that either some plug-in includes something in every page, or you use auto prep-end file in PHP. Check these lines in your "php.ini" configuration file:

```
; Automatically add files before PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-prepend-file
auto_prepend_file =

; Automatically add files after PHP document.
; http://php.net/auto-append-file
auto_append_file =
```

Comment: The problem is 

wp_enqueue_script was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the <code>wp_enqueue_scripts</code>, <code>admin_enqueue_scripts</code>, or <code>init</code> hooks. Please see <a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\functions.php on line 2748

How to solve this?